# Visualize the full chess board from the library python-chess on line command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-chess

I am working a chess game based on this library:
https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/ or https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess

On Jupyter Notebook, if I run this code:

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()
board
```

It will display a nice board (i.e. with colors, shape, looking like a chess board). If I run like this:

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()
print(board)
```

It will display the board in a much more rudimental way with letters.

The problem is that the only way of seeing the nice board, using the "board" command, is if I am using Jupyter Notebook. If I try to run on Visual Studio or line command the command "board" nothing will happen. It seems that the line command will not support the use of "board" (from their website: Supports Python 3.6+ and PyPy3.IPython/Jupyter Notebook integration).

Is there a way around this? In other words, can I still run "board" on command line and visualize the nice chess board?

Comment: You can't do in command line, just jupyter notebook.
Please check https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/master/chess/svg.py.
python-chess create svg file...

Answer (score 6):

If all you want to do is simply graphically display a position, you can install and use the [chess-board](https://pypi.org/project/chess-board/) package.  I use it in tandem with the one you are talking about in the following example:

```
import chess

from chessboard import display
from time import sleep

board = chess.Board()

move_list = [
    'e4', 'e5',
    'Qh5', 'Nc6',
    'Bc4', 'Nf6',
    'Qxf7'
]

display.start(board.fen())
while not display.checkForQuit():
    if move_list:
        board.push_san(move_list.pop(0))
        display.update(board.fen())
    sleep(1)
display.terminate()
```

This package however currently feels quite lacking when it comes to flexibility and well... sanity.  You would have to at least open the packages display.py file and add one line at the beginning of the start() function. Otherwise, you will not be able to use display.update().

```
def start(fen=''):
    global gameboard
```

I see you posted this question a long time ago.  Nonetheless, I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 4):

you can use chess.svg

```
import chess.svg
board = chess.Board()
chess.svg.board(board, size=350)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Google Colab you can use the display() function.

```
board = chess.Board()
display(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

The python-chess library also contains the `chess.svg` package that can output SVG images. Here's an example adapted from the [documentation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/svg.html):

```
from cairosvg import svg2png
import chess.svg


board = chess.Board("8/8/8/8/4N3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1")

svg_text = chess.svg.board(
    board,
    fill=dict.fromkeys(board.attacks(chess.E4), "#cc0000cc"),
    arrows=[chess.svg.Arrow(chess.E4, chess.F6, color="#0000cccc")],
    squares=chess.SquareSet(chess.BB_DARK_SQUARES & chess.BB_FILE_B),
    size=350)

with open('example-board.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(svg_text)

svg2png(bytestring=svg_text, write_to='example-board.png')
```

It also converts the SVG image to PNG with `cairosvg`. That produces this PNG image:

[image: Example chess board image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution resorting to IPython is working on Jupyterlab 4.0.7:

1. At the start of your prog simply add:

`from IPython.display import display, clear_output`

2. then clear previous image before displaying next one:

```
clear_output(wait=True)
display(boardsvg)
```

Here is a complete example inspired from the doc of python-chess:

```py
import chess.engine
from IPython.display import display, clear_output 
board = chess.Board()
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(r"/usr/local/Cellar/stockfish/16/bin/stockfish")
while not board.is_game_over():
    result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
    #print(result.move)
    board.push(result.move)
    boardsvg = chess.svg.board(board, size=350)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(boardsvg)
engine.quit()
```

where `/usr/local/Cellar/stockfish/16/bin/stockfish` is the path to the stockfish engine installed on my mac (with `brew install stockfish`).

*Note that you must have installed the `chess` package previously on your jupyter, e.g. by running `%pip install chess` in a code cell).*

Comment: Please recommend using best practices for modern Jupyter in your answer. Specifically, in your last line you should advise `%pip install chess`. In 2019, the magic variations of the install commands that can be run inside an active notebook were added to insure that the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running, see more about the magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). The exclamation point used in association with the install commands when running inside...

Comment: <continued> an active notebook commands doesn't insure the installation occurs in the proper environment because it just sends it off to a temporary shell instance, which may or may not be connected to the environment where the kernel is running, depending on how the system is set up. This possible inconsistency is avoided by using the magic version and is why it was added. More at top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about why the exclamation point for installations is deficient and can lead to issues.

Comment: <continued> I should point out this use of the magic install commands is nearly universal now everywhere. It is true for modern Jupyter (JupyterLab 4+ and Jupyter Notebook 7+) and even JupyterLite now. I say that to preface bringing up that there is one popular place that it isn't universal yet, frustratingly. The fork of Jupyter that Google Colab was customized off is very old at this point now and predates the addition of the magic install commands and so they don't work there. Sadly, a lot of people are familiar with Google Colab, too, and so t ruins the 'universality' for now.

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I edited the answer accordingly. Note that the magic character `%` is now also working on Colab (I just checked), so we live in a perfect world :-D

Comment: This is definitely good news!